# Find the maximum side length of a regular triangle that can be drawn within a rectangle whose side lengths are A and B.

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

I have to write a code to solve that problem. I couldn't actually get a solution that works.

I thought about something to do with The Law of Cosines:
$x² = A² + B² - A*B*cos(X)$.

Turns out that a found the solution code made by some Chinese guy, but I couldn't understand what's going on. What mathematical theorems or laws he is using to sustain the solution. See below:

`cout << min(2.0*sqrt(b*b- sqrt(3) * a * b + a*a ) , 2.0*min(a,b)/sqrt(3));`

The first parameter in the min function, is pretty similar to The Cosine Law, so I think it might have something to do with this. But, why $\sqrt{3}$ and why it is multiplied by $2.0$?

The second parameter, I'm not sure what it mean.

And, why he is using the min function instead of max function since we're searching for the maximum side length.

Comment: I would have answered the length of the diagonal...

Comment: A regular polygon has all sides equal and all angles equal. So, by that definition a regular triangle would be an equilateral triangle and there is no need to apply the Law of Cosines.

Answer (score 1):

The height of an equilateral triangle is $\frac {\sqrt 3}2$ times the length of a side.  The second entry in the min is for cases where the rectangle is rather long compared to its height so the size of the triangle is constrained by the height.  I don't understand the first entry in the min.  It seems like it should just be the long side of the rectangle because if the rectangle is close to square the limit will be the side of the triangle along the side of the rectangle.  It could be the first entry is imagining putting the triangle with one corner at the corner of the rectangle, but then you would want a max to take the larger triangle.

Answer (score 0):

If the vertices of the triangle are:

$$
A(0,0),
\quad \quad \quad
B(x_b,y_b),
\quad \quad \quad
C(x_c,y_c)
$$

with $0 \le x_c \le x_b$ and $0 \le y_b \le y_c$, imposing it to be a regular triangle:

$$
\begin{cases}
\overline{AB} = \overline{BC} \\
\overline{BC} = \overline{CA} \\
\end{cases}
\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad
(x_c,y_c) = \left(\frac{x_b-\sqrt{3}\,y_b}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}\,x_b+y_b}{2}\right)
$$

from which:

$$
\overline{AB} = \overline{BC} = \overline{CA} = \sqrt{x_b^2+y_b^2} =: L(x_b,y_b)\,.
$$

All that remains is to maximize $L$ bound to $0 \le x_b,x_c \le b$ and $0 \le y_b,y_c \le h$, from which:

$$
L_{\max} =
\begin{cases}
L\left(\frac{2\,h}{\sqrt{3}},0\right) = \frac{2\,h}{\sqrt{3}} & \text{if} \; h \le \frac{\sqrt{3}\,b}{2} \\
L\left(b,\frac{b}{\sqrt{3}}\right) = \frac{2\,b}{\sqrt{3}} & \text{if} \; h \ge \frac{2\,b}{\sqrt{3}} \\
L\left(b,\sqrt{3\,b^2-4\sqrt{3}\,b\,h+4\,h^2}\right) = 2\sqrt{b^2-\sqrt{3}\,b\,h+h^2} & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}.
$$

Comment: Thak you so much for your answer. However I don't get it how you evaluate the coodinate $(x_c,y_c)$